# SQL join between tables with specific characteristics

Tags: sql, join, teradata

espero que puedan ayudarme!!! tengo un par de tablas SQL

**tabla A (volumen)** contiene una estructura sin valores repetidos, imaginemos 100 registros

orderid, date, origin, destiny, piece
1,
2,
3,
..
..
100

**table b** (detail) ccontiene los detalles de escaneo de cada orden, por tanto esta tabla puede tener multiples registros para la misma orden, imaginemos que hay 3000 registros

orderid, scan, date, time, comment

1   **12**    5/5    1240    retain 1
1   **12**    5/6     532    **retain 2**
1   76    5/6     221
1   45    6/6    1325
1   **12**    6/6     441    **label-12312**
..
..
100

**estoy buscando crear una tabla que me relacione todo el proceso de cada orden.**

si ven, los mensajes que estoy buscando tienen el scan type=12

order id, (ultimo mesg retain desde tabla detail), mensaje label

1, retain2, label-12312
2, retain, label-6543
..
100,retain ,

el problema es que por mas intento hacer esto con leftjoins, inner joins, etc... la tabla de salida me da mas de los 100 registros originales, hay lineas que se me duplican.

muchas gracias

Comment: Por favor traduce pues estás en SO en español

Comment: Por favor añade el motor de base de datos que estas usando, es decir, SQL Server, MySQL, ORACLE u otro.

Comment: teradata 16.10.... gracias

Comment: No se entiende cuales son las reglas de tu select. No se entiende cuales son las tablas y los campos que queres unir. Mostra el query que intentaste, mostra la salida, y la salida que queres.. y sobre todo porque selecciona el registro que selecciona

Answer (score 0):

falta información :
- motor de BD.
- estructura de tablas.

aun así :

```
select distinct 
  A.orderid,
  B.scan,
  B.date,
  B.time
from
   volumen as A inner join detail B on A.orderid = B.orderid
order by  A.orderid
```

Eso te entregara todas las ordenes que tengan detalle
si quieres listar todas las ordenes, tenga o  no detalle debes hacer un left join.

```
select distinct 
  A.orderid,
  B.scan,
  B.date,
  B.time
from
   volumen as A left join detail B on A.orderid = B.orderid
```

Comment: esto le va a devolver todos los registros, no los que el dice. Mejor esperar a que aclare bien que datos quiere y porque... y la db la puso, es teradata